# Asking a question being on mobile view broke some style

Tags: bug, design, asking-questions, mobile-web

When using a mobile web [asking a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) redirects you to the full site version but it seems that some styles are not applied correctly. In particular for inbox and achievements popups:

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Repro’d in Firefox Nightly 84.0a1.

Comment: Reproed on chrome 86.0 on Android